# Docker registry (local): how to limit the number of unique tags per image?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, continuous-deployment, docker-registry

I'm working on a CI/CD process for some project and decided that every image will have its own unique tag (#build). This is done so rollback will be possible (I'm on Swarm mode)

The problem is that it will bloat the Docker registry pretty quickly.

Is it possible to control the number of tags/images? (e.g. deleting the oldest if limit has been reached)

Answer (score 2):

If you have private registry and you have Enterprise version (Docker Trusted Registry), then you can set tag limit with FIFO principle. Also it is possible to set pruning policies, e.g. by age.
[More info.](https://docs.docker.com/ee/dtr/user/tag-pruning/)

With regular Docker Hub, you might achieve something similar with WebHooks and making your own code.

Some third party tools for cleaning basic private registry, by using registry v2 API:

- [registry-cli](https://github.com/andrey-pohilko/registry-cli)
- [cleanreg](https://github.com/hcguersoy/cleanreg)

Comment: Sadly it's not an Enterprise version

Comment: Seems like there are some 3rd party tools for regular private registry e.g : https://github.com/hcguersoy/cleanreg and https://github.com/andrey-pohilko/registry-cli